# How to get text before space from MYSQL to Java

Tags: java, mysql

So I have the column 'Adress' which has both street and number in there.
So for example:

```
 Londonstreet 13
```

And I got 2 textfields, for street and number which have to get filled up with:

```
 Street: Londonstreet
 Number: 13
```

If I do

```
Street.setText(rs.getString("adress");
```

It puts 'Londonstreet 13' in the Street textfield, while I want just the streetname.

How to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using regular expressions

```
    String address= rs.getString("adress");
    String[] addressPart =address.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
    Street.setText(addressPart[0]);
    Number.setText(addressPart[1]);
```